How to get the merchant-id or how do i get the id that connects my user to get paid via PayPal?
At the moment, I'm going through the onboarding process. Call this API call, where I can get the action URL, so that the onboarding starts. So I request this API call:
https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/customer/partner-referrals

With this payload:
{
    "tracking_id": "868gkjhkhjlklj",
    "operations": [{
    "operation": "API_INTEGRATION",
    "api_integration_preference": {
          "rest_api_integration": {
                "integration_method": "PAYPAL",
                "integration_type": "THIRD_PARTY",
                "third_party_details": {
                "features": [
                    "PAYMENT",
                    "REFUND"
                 ]
          }
      }
  }
 }],
   "products": [
    "EXPRESS_CHECKOUT"
 ],
 "legal_consents": [{
    "type": "SHARE_DATA_CONSENT",
    "granted": true
}]
}

I get a response of this JSON:
{
    "links": [
        {
           "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/customer/partner-referrals/M2FkMjQ2MjMtMmRkZC00MjYxLWE2NWQtMmVmMjJlZjU1OTE2MTk4SkhnOFViTHhORHh3cUM3Q1BqRWc2dHJzYXJMcGxLMzRKN1ZpR0Jldz12Mg==",
            "rel": "self",
            "method": "GET",
            "description": "Read Referral Data shared by the Caller."
          },
        {
            "href": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/bizsignup/partner/entry?referralToken=M2FkMjQ2MjMtMmRkZC00MjYxLWE2NWQtMmVmMjJlZjU1OTE2MTk4SkhnOFViTHhORHh3cUM3Q1BqRWc2dHJzYXJMcGxLMzRKN1ZpR0Jldz12Mg==",
            "rel": "action_url",
            "method": "GET",
            "description": "Target WEB REDIRECT URL for the next action. Customer should be redirected to this URL in the browser."
        }
    ]
}

And I add this action_url to the JavaScript or link button on the page:
        <div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
        <script>
            (function (d, s, id) {
                var js, ref = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                    js = d.createElement(s);
                    js.id = id;
                    js.async = true;
                    js.src = "https://www.paypal.com/webapps/merchantboarding/js/lib/lightbox/partner.js";
                    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
                }
            }(document, "script", "paypal-js"));
        </script>
        <a data-paypal-button="true" href="<action_url>&displayMode=minibrowser" target="PPFrame">Sign up for PayPal</a>
    </div>

This is the link on my screen where I go through the onboarding:

Then I'm in the onboarding process.

I don't understand what to do next; there is no documentation that I can find to get the merchant_id and store it against my user in the database so that I can use this merchant_id and allow the merchant / seller to be paid for their goods. What do I do next?
I'm using PayPal Rest API V2, should I use V1? or continue to use V2 as its a new implementation?

You need to set up a Webhook listener on your website, and configure a Webhook for the MERCHANT.ONBOARDING.COMPLETED event on your PayPal account.  Once the merchant has completed their onboarding process, PayPal will send a notification to your Webhook, where you can then act accordingly (add the merchant_id to your database and mark them as "onboarded").
PayPal's Webhooks Guide is what you want to look at.
Along with the Integrate Webhooks page, that should get you up and running.
